# Validating password with Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

A task I'm working on requires a password to be validated with the following rules:

- Must start with a capital letter (A-Z)
- Have eight characters (minimum)
- One of these characters must be a ! ^ or &
- And password must end with a number.

This is the Regular Expression I have so far:

```
'/^\p{Lu}(?=.*[!^&])\d$.{8,}$/';
// Start with a capital letter: ^\p{Lu}
// At least 8 characters: .{8,}
// One of these characters must be a: (?=.*[!^&])
// Must end with a number: \d$
```

The expression for eight characters and a number work but the special character and capital letter doesn't work so I'm turning to the experts for this who could push me in the right direction.

Comment: Why use a substandard pattern like that. Is this 'homework' ?

Comment: It _must_ be homework, because in the real world those restrictions would be rather idi*tic, and decrease security.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern already matches an uppercase char at the start, so it should be followed by 7 or more chars to make it at least 8 or more chars.

You can also match a digit at the end, and then you can match 6 or more chars before it.

If the pattern should have 8 characters minimum, you can use:

```
^\p{Lu}(?=[^!^&]*[!^&]).{6,}\d$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\p{Lu}` Match any uppercase letter
- `(?=[^!^&]*[!^&])` Positive lookahead, assert one of `!` `^` `&`
- `.{6,}` Match any char 6 or more times
- `\d$` Match a digit at the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OOwfbr/1)

Note that the `.` matches any char, including spaces.